# What is the best way to write a function in R where the output depends on an argument?

Tags: r, function

I want to write a function that calculates income tax in the UK, potentially inside a package. The precise formula changes regularly, every year say, but instead of writing a new function every time it changes, I want to use an argument, 'year', that controls the behavior of the function. So for example:

```r
income_tax(x = '25000', year = '2019/20')
```

where x is a vector of incomes and year specifies the tax rules to apply.

What is the best way to organize and manage this function, considering that the formula for each year can be quite complex, and new updates will be added each year?

Is there an object orientated solution? Or write internal functions inside for each year and some if/else logic inside the main function?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a meta-question, as it's not specific to R, but... I imagine that even though the years are different, there are some parts that are common (in form, even if not in all the details) to several years.  I'd be tempted to have a list of functions (one per year) that gets called by `income_tax`, and these in turn are bespoke, but can call common functionality:

```
year_fns <- list(
`2019/20` = function(x, ...) {
   taxable <- post_allowance(x, 11000)
   # now some bespoke stuff for this year
   if (taxable > 100e3 ){
     ...
   }
   ....
   final_value
},
`2020/21` = #another function 
...
)

post_allowance  <- function(x, allowance) {
# some common functionality
}
```

and then you'd just calculate income tax via

```
income_tax <- function(x, year, ...) {
   year_fns[[year]](x, ...)
}
```

This may take a bit of getting used to, but it's a beauty of R that functions are as easy to handle as numbers, strings etc.  So we're looking-up the correct function to call in the `year_fns[[year]]` part, and then calling that function with the `(x,...)` part

Answer (score 0):

In R you can pass around expressions (or parts of it), just like numbers and strings, meaning that they can be deployed as arguments in function calls. Most likely, the function expression() may suit your needs.